# SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest breaks ASP.Net server side validation

Tags: 2010, validation, runwithelevatedprivileges

I have a Web Part which is using `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`, and thus needs to call `SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest`. However, this apparently causes it to ignore all ASP.Net validators server side. The validation functions are being called, but the `IsValid` result seems to be either overwritten or ignored. What is causing this, and how do I fix it?

Broadly speaking, I have a Visual Web Part that is a form. It has a bunch of input controls, with various required, regular expression, and custom validators. And basically:

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(
         delegate { do a bunch of stuff including creating list items });
}
```

but a lot more complicated because there are a bunch of views and different submit buttons.

Originally I had `SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();` in `Page_Load`. I have also tried placing it directly before the `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` in the click event handler, but that has not resolved the issue.

Comment: What do you mean with thus needs to call `SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest`? Can you post your code?

Comment: @RobertLindgren [If the method that is passed to the RunWithElevatedPrivileges method includes a write operation, either of the SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest() or SPWeb.ValidateFormDigest() methods should be called before a call is made to RunWithElevatedPrivileges.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.validateformdigest.aspx)

Comment: Ah you're making a write operation in the elevation, it was not fully clear from your question